# What are the merits of Korea filling a complaint against the U.S. for the Inflation Reduction Act?

Tags: international-law, wto

> Korea’s Industry Minister Lee Chang-yang earlier this week said he was
> considering filing a complaint with the World Trade Organization
> against the act. Some 25 lawmakers in South Korea proposed a
> resolution against it, urging the US not to “discriminate” against
> foreign electric car and battery makers.

https://archive.ph/1bzof#selection-4725.0-4733.110

In my understanding, the Inflation Reduction Act is aimed towards diversifying the U.S. supply chain. If so, then it can be argued that this is done for national security. Then wouldn't South Korea's complaint be dismissed? What are the merits of Korea filling a complaint against the U.S. for the Inflation Reduction Act?

Comment: In my personal impression in the US you can justify any legal act whatsoever with the claim 'national security' and this is generally accepted as a valid reason, regardless of what the law is actually about. This does not work nearly as well internationally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> then it can be argued that this is done for national security. Then wouldn't South Korea's complaint be dismissed?

Not necessarily. In the Ukraine-Russia case (DS512) the WTO panel held that it had jurisdiction to decide whether invoked measures could be reasonably construed as pertaining to the claimed goal

> Specifically, the Panel found that, while the chapeau of Article XXI(b) allows a Member to take action “which it considers necessary” for the protection of its essential security interests, this discretion is limited to circumstances that objectively fall within the scope of the three subparagraphs of Article XXI(b) (see paras. 7.101 and 7.53-7.100). Consequently, the Panel rejected Russia's jurisdictional argument that Article XXI(b)(iii) was totally “self-judging” (paras. 7.102-7.104).

That case was about road traffic, and arguably less clearly related to the present one than, say, even the (Trump-era) aluminium WTO cases. It seems however that the Biden administration has relaxed some if not all of those measures, so it's unclear if the WTO panels will proceed with those cases, e.g. DS548 was mutually settled, although (the earlier) DS544 appears to still be "on" I'm not sure exactly what's going on with that one. (N.B. it seems that one, in which China is the complainant, will get a panel decision by the end of 2022; the deadline was extended due to the "complexity of the dispute".) So we may yet see cases that pertain to industrial products and claims of national security actually decided by a WTO panel. It's unclear apriori what decisions might look like, but we can say fairly certainly that they won't be dismissed on the defendant magically waving "national security" without any further look by the WTO.

Whether South Korea actually plans to litigate is another matter though. Allies seem to more often mutually settle these before panel decision stage.

---

I'm not entirely sure what the new US law requires, but "from the helicopter" the dispute seem to involve (among other things) incentives that some components be made in the US, or in any case, not in China. I found a 3rd party [summary](https://prosperousamerica.org/inflation-reduction-act-knifes-the-multilateral-trading-system-heres-what-ustr-needs-to-do/) of the provisions in that regard:

> to get the full $7,500 credit, the car has to:
>
> - Have final assembly in North America; and
> - 40% of the critical minerals in the battery must be sourced from the United States, or one of the 20 countries with whom we have an FTA. This 40% increases to 50% in 2024, 60% in 2025, 70% in 2026 and 80% in 2027.

That's actually somewhat but not entirely similar to a case on photovoltaic [CSPV] products (DS562) that China lost at panel stage, although they are appealing that one. In that case though, the US simply imposed/claimed safeguard measures after China's various incentives to build CSPV products resulted in a massive production boost (and thus cheap exports to the US). But even if China did the same with battery components, the US [counter]measures seem a bit different in this case, so a WTO complaint won't necessarily have the same fate. Mind you, what the US law seem to do is *not* give some tax breaks if some components are made in China (actually a range of countries--those sans an FTA with the US), so it's not an outright import ban from China, more like a subsidy for domestic/non-China ones. Generally speaking, [it seems](https://institutdelors.eu/en/publications/les-subventions-au-coeur-de-la-guerre-commerciale-2/) that subsidies aimed at increasing domestic production are the most difficult to litigate against in the WTO framework, in terms of burden of proof etc. It's because trade disputes are not like criminal law, where something is just not allowed and you put the offender in prison. For dispute resolution at the WTO, have show by how much a possibly complex incentives plan would affect your exports, which can be hard to do before it's actually in effect for a while. So countries sometimes hedge their bets by implementing their own subsidies schemes "in return", so see cases like the Boeing-Airbus saga, made up of multiple "parallel" WTO cases.

Oh, and it looks like the EU [is not](https://federalnewsnetwork.com/world-news/2022/08/eu-says-us-electric-vehicle-tax-credit-could-break-wto-rules/) happy either with the US Inflation Reduction Act:

> “The European Union is deeply concerned by this new, potential, trans-Atlantic trade barrier,” European Commission spokeswoman Miriam Garcia Ferrer said. “We think that it’s discriminatory, that it’s discriminating against foreign producers in relation to U.S. producers.” [...]
>
> The commission agrees that tax credits are “an important incentive to drive the demand for electric vehicles” and ultimately to help reduce greenhouse gas emissions. “But we need to ensure that the measures introduced are fair,” the spokeswoman said. [...]
>
> [...] the commission is deeply concerned about the domestic U.S. content and assembly requirements in the tax credit plan and claims this only favors certain mineral-rich countries, to the detriment of EU products exported to America.
>
> EU subsidy schemes, the commission said, are available for domestic and foreign producers alike.

FWTW, a few days after the EU made those remarks, the DOE published the [list](https://afdc.energy.gov/laws/inflation-reduction-act) of qualifying vehicles. There are some EU (and Japanese) manufacturers on the list, so I guess it's not certain the EU (at least) will pursue this complaint in a more formal manner. The Korean ones are completely absent though.